# Faster projected-norm (quadratic-form, metric-matrix...) style computations

Tags: matlab, performance, linear-algebra, scilab

I need to perform lots of evaluations of the form

```
X(:,i)' * A * X(:,i)   i = 1...n
```

where X(:,i) is a vector and A is a symmetric matrix. Ostensibly, I can either do this in a loop

```
for i=1:n
    z(i) = X(:,i)' * A * X(:,i)
end
```

which is slow, or vectorise it as

```
z = diag(X' * A * X)
```

which wastes RAM unacceptably when X has a lot of columns. Currently I am compromising on

```
Y = A * X
for i=1:n
    z(i) = Y(:,i)' * X(:,i)
end
```

which is a little faster/lighter but still seems unsatisfactory.

I was hoping there might be some matlab/scilab idiom or trick to achieve this result more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in MATLAB:

```
z = sum(X.*(A*X));
```

This gives results equivalent to [Federico's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568939/faster-projected-norm-quadratic-form-metric-matrix-style-computations/2568985#2568985) using the function [DOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html), but should run slightly faster. This is because the [DOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html) function internally computes the result the same way as I did above using the [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html) function. However, [DOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html) also has additional input argument checks and extra computation for cases where you are dealing with complex numbers, which is extra overhead you probably don't want or need.

**A note on computational efficiency:**

Even though the time difference is small between how fast the two methods run, if you are going to be performing the operation *many* times over it's going to start to add up. To test the relative speeds, I created two 100-by-100 matrices of random values and timed the two methods over many runs to get an average execution time:

```
    METHOD        AVERAGE EXECUTION TIME
--------------------------------------------
Z = sum(X.*Y);        0.0002595 sec
Z = dot(X,Y);         0.0003627 sec
```

Using [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html) instead of [DOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html) therefore reduces the execution time of this operation by about 28% for matrices with around 10,000 elements. The larger the matrices, the more negligible this difference will be between the two methods.

To summarize, if this computation represents a *significant bottleneck* in how fast your code is running, I'd go with the solution using [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html). Otherwise, either solution should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
z = dot(X, A*X)
```

I don't have Matlab here to test, but it works on Octave, so I expect Matlab to have an analogous  `dot()` function.

From Octave's help:

```
  -- Function File:  dot (X, Y, DIM)
     Computes the dot product of two vectors. If X and Y are matrices,
     calculate the dot-product along the first non-singleton dimension.
     If the optional argument DIM is given, calculate the dot-product
     along this dimension.
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, gnovice's answer in Scilab would be

```
z = sum(X .* Y, 1)'
```