# Is there a matlab built-in that calculates the quadratic form (x'*A*x)?

Tags: performance, matlab, linear-algebra, quadratic

Pretty straightforward question: Given an N x N symmetric matrix A and an N-vector x, is there a built-in Matlab function to calculate `x'*A*x`?  i.e., instead of `y = x'*A*x`, is there a function `quadraticform` s.t. `y = quadraticform(A, x)`?

Obviously I can just do `y = x'*A*x`, but I need performance and it seems like there ought to be a way to take advantage of

1. `A` is symmetric
2. The left and right multipliers are the same vector

If there's not a single built-in function, is there method that's faster than `x'*A*x`?  OR, is the Matlab parser smart enough to optimize `x'*A*x`?  If so, can you point me to a place in the documentation that verifies the fact?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568939/faster-projected-norm-quadratic-form-metric-matrix-style-computations

Comment: Thanks.  That *is* a little faster, but I'm going to leave it open to see if there are any other suggestions (technically it's not the same question, but does get to the same point).  sum(x.*(A*x)) doesn't take advantage of symmetry or repetition...  It's such a ubiquitous calculation that it seems like there'd be a built-in...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find such a built-in function, and I have an idea why.

`y=x'*A*x` can be written as a sum of `n^2` terms `A(i,j)*x(i)*x(j)`, where `i` and `j` runs from `1` to `n` (where `A` is an `nxn` matrix). `A` is symmetric: `A(i,j) = A(j,i)` for all `i` and `j`. Due to symmetry, every term appears twice in the sum, except for those where `i` equals `j`. So we have `n*(n+1)/2` different terms. Each has two floating-point multiplications, so a naive method would need `n*(n+1)` multiplications in total. It is easy to see that the naive calculation of `x'*A*x`, that is, calculating `z=A*x` and then `y=x'*z`, also needs `n*(n+1)` multiplications. However, there is a faster way to sum our `n*(n+1)/2` different terms: for every `i`, we can factor out `x(i)`, which means that only `n*(n-1)/2+3*n` multiplications is enough. But this does not really help: the running time of the calculation of `y=x'*A*x` is still `O(n^2)`.

So, I think that the calculation of quadratic forms cannot be done faster than `O(n^2)`, and since this can also be achieved by the formula `y=x'*A*x`, there would be no real advantage of a special "quadraticform" function.

**=== UPDATE ===**

I've written the function "quadraticform" in C, as a Matlab extension:

```
// y = quadraticform(A, x)
#include "mex.h" 

/* Input Arguments */
#define A_in prhs[0]
#define x_in prhs[1]

/* Output Arguments */
#define y_out plhs[0] 

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  mwSize mA, nA, n, mx, nx;
  double *A, *x;
  double z, y;
  int i, j, k;

  if (nrhs != 2) { 
      mexErrMsgTxt("Two input arguments required."); 
  } else if (nlhs > 1) {
      mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments."); 
  }

  mA = mxGetM(A_in);
  nA = mxGetN(A_in);
  if (mA != nA)
    mexErrMsgTxt("The first input argument must be a quadratic matrix.");
  n = mA;

  mx = mxGetM(x_in);
  nx = mxGetN(x_in);
  if (mx != n || nx != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("The second input argument must be a column vector of proper size.");

  A = mxGetPr(A_in);
  x = mxGetPr(x_in);
  y = 0.0;
  k = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    z = 0.0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
      z += A[k + j] * x[j];
    z *= x[i];
    y += A[k + i] * x[i] * x[i] + z + z;
    k += n;
  }

  y_out = mxCreateDoubleScalar(y);
}
```

I saved this code as "quadraticform.c", and compiled it with Matlab:

```
mex -O quadraticform.c
```

I wrote a simple performance test to compare this function with x'*A*x:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

sizes = int32(logspace(2, 3, 25));
nsizes = length(sizes);
etimes = zeros(nsizes, 2); % Matlab vs. C
nrepeats = 100;
h = waitbar(0, 'Please wait...');
for i = 1 : nrepeats
  for j = 1 : nsizes
    n = sizes(j);
    A = randn(n); 
    A = (A + A') / 2;
    x = randn(n, 1);
    if randn > 0
      start = tic;
      y1 = x' * A * x;
      etimes(j, 1) = etimes(j, 1) + toc(start);
      start = tic;
      y2 = quadraticform(A, x);
      etimes(j, 2) = etimes(j, 2) + toc(start);      
    else
      start = tic;
      y2 = quadraticform(A, x);
      etimes(j, 2) = etimes(j, 2) + toc(start);      
      start = tic;
      y1 = x' * A * x;
      etimes(j, 1) = etimes(j, 1) + toc(start);
    end;
    if abs((y1 - y2) / y2) > 1e-10
      error('"x'' * A * x" is not equal to "quadraticform(A, x)"');
    end;
    waitbar(((i - 1) * nsizes + j) / (nrepeats * nsizes), h);
  end;
end;
close(h);
clear A x y;
etimes = etimes / nrepeats;

n = double(sizes);
n2 = n .^ 2.0;
i = nsizes - 2 : nsizes;
n2_1 = mean(etimes(i, 1)) * n2 / mean(n2(i));
n2_2 = mean(etimes(i, 2)) * n2 / mean(n2(i));

figure;
loglog(n, etimes(:, 1), 'r.-', 'LineSmoothing', 'on');
hold on;
loglog(n, etimes(:, 2), 'g.-', 'LineSmoothing', 'on');
loglog(n, n2_1, 'k-', 'LineSmoothing', 'on');
loglog(n, n2_2, 'k-', 'LineSmoothing', 'on');
axis([n(1) n(end) 1e-4 1e-2]);
xlabel('Matrix size, n');
ylabel('Running time (a.u.)');
legend('x'' * A * x', 'quadraticform(A, x)', 'O(n^2)', 'Location', 'NorthWest');

W = 16 / 2.54; H = 12 / 2.54; dpi = 100;
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0, 0, W, H]);
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [W, H]);
print(gcf, sprintf('-r%d',dpi), '-dpng', 'quadraticformtest.png');
```

The result is very interesting. The running time of both `x'*A*x` and `quadraticform(A,x)` converges to `O(n^2)`, but the former has a smaller factor:

[image: quadraticformtest.png]

Comment: I agree the lower bound is n*(n+1)/2 terms (each one a multiplication of 3 floats, then sum them all).  If Matlab does x'*A*x as z = A*x, then y = x'*z, that's N^2 + N terms, and probably throw in an N to allocate/deallocate z.  I'm in a regime where N is generally fixed, and the difference between N^2 + 2*N and N^2/2  + N/2 is important.

Comment: If you have Matlab Compiler, then you can write your "quadraticform" function in C, and call it from Matlab. (Matlab Compiler compiles a MEX file, which is essentially a DLL on Windows.) You can use the method I suggested in the answer, it's pretty simple to implement, and scales as `n*(n-1)/2+3*n`.

Comment: You can do that without MATLAB Compiler.

Comment: @SamRoberts Yes, you can compile C DLLs without Matlab, but I would not want to struggle with the internal representation of Matlab matrices.

Comment: @kol I mean you can create MEX functions with just MATLAB, you don't need MATLAB Compiler.

Comment: @SamRoberts Ah, yes. You are right. It was a long time ago... :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I wrote the mex file and it's actually slightly slower than just doing x'*A*x, which is still the fastest way I've found.  The c code (sans all of the extra checks) is here:  https://gist.github.com/1428255   I would guess the potential performance gain is being offset by the overhead in calling the mex file?

Comment: @dantswain There is some overhead from making a function call, but if it's just one call that's probably not going to make a huge difference. I would guess that MATLAB is making some BLAS-level optimisations that the C compiler does not take advantage of.

Comment: @SamRoberts I've written the "quadraticform" function in C and compiled it with Matlab. The Matlab test is currently running, please be patient :)

Comment: @kol This is great work, but to properly benchmark things in MATLAB you really need to time it within a function, not a script, otherwise MATLAB does not make most of the optimisations that it can. Try using Steve Eddins' `timeit` utility from the MATLAB Central File Exchange, which will take care of a lot of subtle issues to do with timings, such as warming up the function for you.

Comment: @SamRoberts Thanks for the tip. As a fast test, I changed the test code to be a function, put x'*A*x into a function, added warmup repeats, and calculated median instead of mean. None of these changed the result significantly.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think the bottom line for me was that `x'*A*x` was fastest, so I went with that.  I would have split the answer credit if I could :-/

Comment: In MATLAB `x' * A * x` is done using BLAS Library which is vectorized and use multi threading. If you add that to your `C` code I think you'll be able to beat MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB is clever enough to recognise and optimise some sorts of compound matrix expression, and I believe (although I can't definitely confirm) that the quadratic form is one of the optimisations that it does make.

However, it's not the sort of thing MathWorks tend to document, because
a) it will typically only be optimised within functions, not in scripts, at the command line or in debugging
b) it may only work in some circumstances, such as for real nonsparse A
c) it may change from release to release, so they don't want you to rely on it
d) it's one of the proprietary things that make MATLAB so good.

To confirm, you could try comparing timings for `y=x'*A*x` against `B=A*x; y=x'*B`. You could also try `feature('accel','off')`, which will turn most of those sort of optimisations off.

Finally, if you contact MathWorks support, you might be able to get one of the developers to confirm whether the optimisation is being made.

Comment: "MATLAB is clever enough to recognise and optimise that sort of expression" - Can you prove this claim somehow? None of us know, what happens in the background, when Matlab compiles and runs such an expression.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see what Octave does with this, I mean, is there any optimization. Octave is open source, so if someone has time (lots of time...), it's not impossible to figure out.